# Translation help! 置いておきます

Tags: translation

置いて is the て-form of 置く(to place). So what does おきます stand for?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7):

ておく is a common verb inflection to mean "to do in preparation for something," so 置{お}いておきます means "to place (in preparation for something in the future)."

For example, 鍵{かぎ}を椅子{いす}の上{うえ}に置{お}いておきました would mean "I placed the keys on the chair," with some implications like "so you could pick it up later" or "so it's more convenient for you when you're leaving the house" etc.